# cannot connect to "office outlook" with SharePoint Foundation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, outlook, ms-office

I have installed SharePoint 2010 and office 2010 in my machine. It is 64-bit OS. I have created an external list in sharePoint. I want to export that list into office outlook. But "connect to outlook" icon is not greyed out. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx
You have a few things you need to ensure.  One is that you have to be using the 32bit browser on your x64 machine.  Also I know there are problems with 64bit Office not shipping with the controls that support the browser-app integration.  Lastly, the list that you are looking at has to be one that is appropriate to take offline to Outlook.  Not all list types are connectable to Outlook.